# Getting Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: Genesis not found in chain

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, genesis

I am getting the following error in one of the nodes, I have a quorum network running.

> Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: Genesis not found in chain
>   DEBUG[02-19|08:37:08] FS scan times                            list=34.464µs set=5.249µs diff=4.779µs
>   TRACE[02-19|08:37:08] Handled keystore changes                 time=60.931µs
>   DEBUG[02-19|08:37:08] FS scan times                            list=18.141µs set=3.251µs diff=4.014µs
>   TRACE[02-19|08:37:08] Started watching keystore folder         path=/quorum/keystore
>   INFO [02-19|08:37:08] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.2-stable-4d015bb4/linux-amd64/go1.9.3
>   INFO [02-19|08:37:08] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/quorum/geth/chaindata cache=128 handles=1024
>   INFO [02-19|08:37:08] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 2018 Homestead: 1 DAO:  DAOSupport: false EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 1 IsQuorum: true Engine: unknown}"
>   WARN [02-19|08:37:08] Ethash used in full fake mode
>   INFO [02-19|08:37:08] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1337
>   Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: Genesis not found in chain

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you havent initialized the chain with a genesis block. Please see how this is done in quorum-examples. Initialization: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/blob/master/examples/7nodes/raft-init.sh, and starter: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/blob/master/examples/7nodes/raft-start.sh